# Add and remove multiple signers in one transaction

Tags: transactions, xdr, options, cli

Looking at the XDR spec there is only [one signer](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/333387f23a0f205a3c00bdc33cb454e0fda32095/xdr/Stellar-transaction.x#L144-L146) allowed per transaction.

Is there a reason for it, or there is a way to add multiple signers atomically?

I am working on a new command line interface for Stellar ([BB-8](https://github.com/tolitius/bb8)) and would like stay as close to XDR as possible, but also to have friendly human API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the `SetOptionsOp`, that's an **operation** contract. A **transaction** can include up to 100 operations (this constant may be changed in the future). Therefore you can atomically add up to 100 signers.

Comment: ah.. makes sense. just to confirm, does it mean that "setOptions" is yet another "operation" that can be called upto 100 times, and hence the "append" [here](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/2dacfed8b9dc4ce7b42b606cd27857e99b03cc1e/build/transaction.go#L292)?

Comment: Yes, "setOptions" is one of the [operations](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#operation-types) and transaction may contain up to 100 operations.